# integer, printf: is there a way to write an integer as a wide char to console without locale.h?

Tags: c, widechar

suppose I have a Unicode codepoint c (a `uint32`). Is there a way to print this integer to console (as a wide character) without using `locale.h` or `wchar.h`? Thanks.

Comment: What prevents you from using `wchar.h` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use

```
printf("%lc", c);
```

though you really need to make sure that `c` is a `wint_t` (which requires `wchar.h`) rather than a `uint32_t`, even though the two are most likely the same type...

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

```
printf("%u", c);
```